# how does facebook convert heic to jpeg?

Tags: image, facebook, format-conversion, heic

When I upload an image of the `heic` format on Facebook, it converts this file to jpeg before posting it.
Where does the convert happen? In client before sending file to facebook server? Or in the backend server after server receive it?

Comment: Pretty sure they do that server-side. Browsers do not understand this image format, so any conversion would have to implement an algorithm that can unpack/render it first, probably in JavaScript, and I doubt they would go through that trouble.